# How can I start a Python async coroutine eagerly?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, coroutine

Consider the following code:

```py
import asyncio

async def subsubfunc():
    print("    subsubfunc")
    # [some async I/O code here]

async def subfunc():
    print("  subfunc A")
    awaitable = subsubfunc()
    print("  subfunc B")
    await awaitable
    print("  subfunc C")

async def func():
    print("func A")
    awaitable = subfunc()
    print("func B")
    await awaitable
    print("func C")

asyncio.run(func())
```

**Actual output:**

```
func A
func B
  subfunc A
  subfunc B
    subsubfunc
  subfunc C
func C
```

**Desired output:**

```
func A
  subfunc A
    subsubfunc
  subfunc B
  subfunc C
func B
func C
```

More precisely, I would like all work than can be done eagerly to actually be done eagerly (before execution of the caller continues).

The following snippet emulates that, however in a rather hacky way:

```py
import asyncio

async def subsubfunc():
    print("    subsubfunc")
    # [some async I/O code here]

async def subfunc():
    print("  subfunc A")
    awaitable = asyncio.create_task(subsubfunc())
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    print("  subfunc B")
    await awaitable
    print("  subfunc C")

async def func():
    print("func A")
    awaitable = asyncio.create_task(subfunc())
    await asyncio.sleep(0) # subfunc is started here
    await asyncio.sleep(0) # subsubfunc is started here
    print("func B")
    await awaitable
    print("func C")

asyncio.run(func())
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

To clarify: I'd like `func B` and `subfunc B` to print *before* the coroutines complete. Imagine `[some async I/O code here]` to wait for I/O. The caller should continue before the I/O completes. A possible use case for this is if data can (and must) be sent in a non-blocking fashion and then the same coroutine needs to wait for a response and in between the caller is supposed to do additional work.

Comment: To get your output, don’t assign the coroutine, print, and then await it; just await it. It won’t be scheduled until you await it.

Answer (score 2):

When you say, for example ...

```py
    awaitable = subsubfunc()
```

... and then later you say ...

```py
    await awaitable
```

... those two statements are equivalent to the single statement:

```py
    await subsubfunc()
```

Note that the statement `awaitable = subsubfunc()` does not cause anything to run. It is only when you `await` an async function call (or a reference to such a function call, for example variable `awaitable`) that something gets to run.

So you just need to move a couple of  `await` statements:

```py
import asyncio

async def subsubfunc():
    print("    subsubfunc")
    # [some async I/O code here]

async def subfunc():
    print("  subfunc A")
    awaitable = subsubfunc()
    await awaitable
    print("  subfunc B")
    print("  subfunc C")

async def func():
    print("func A")
    awaitable = subfunc()
    await awaitable
    print("func B")
    print("func C")

asyncio.run(func())
```

Which can be simplified to:

```py
import asyncio

async def subsubfunc():
    print("    subsubfunc")
    # [some async I/O code here]

async def subfunc():
    print("  subfunc A")
    await subsubfunc()
    print("  subfunc B")
    print("  subfunc C")

async def func():
    print("func A")
    await subfunc()
    print("func B")
    print("func C")

asyncio.run(func())
```

Prints:

```
func A
  subfunc A
    subsubfunc
  subfunc B
  subfunc C
func B
func C
```

Comment: However I'd like the caller to continue after the subfunction starts but before it completes. Imagine the placeholder `[some async I/O code here]` to be code that waits for I/O. I would like everything up to that point to run synchronously, and then I would like `subfunc B` and `func B` to print before the I/O completes.

Comment: Regarding your "hacky" way of solving this: Creating a task as you do with `create_task` is the proper way to allow `subsubfunc` to run and allow `subfunc` to continue to run without having to block in the completion of `subsubfunc`. So far so good. But the whole idea of trying to get the output of one task to be displayed between two lines of another coroutine for which probably the only way to do that is to know how many times you have to issue calls to `sleep`  (twice in `func`) strikes me as ridiculous. Your hacky way of doing it is probably the only solution. But to what real problem?

Comment: And I am sure English is not your fist language, so no fault there, but your use of the "eagerly" is not clear. In your description you do seem to suggest that there may be coroutines running concurrently. But your initial piece of code (the one before the "hacky" solution) does not indicate that at all and hence my solution that does not create a new task. I just though that perhaps you misunderstood what `awaitable = subsubfunc()` was doing.

Comment: Yeah sorry my problem statement wasn't very clear. I meant "start eagerly" as opposed to "start lazily". I edited the question to add an example use case.

Comment: The OP asked how to make a coroutine execute eagerly. This answer simply states that coroutines do not execute eagerly. The other answer references `asyncio.create_task()`, which is documented as doing what OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

The OP asked how to run coroutines eagerly, and so far all of the responses have been "coroutines are not executed eagerly", which are not answers.

The documented answer is to use `asyncio.create_task(coroutine)`, which turns a coroutine into a task, which schedules it for execution. The task is then awaitable, just like a coroutine.

More information on the python docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks

Comment: This doesn't guarantee eager execution.

Comment: It's not executed eagerly, but it is scheduled eagerly, which is about the best you can do, I think (and better than python will do on its own).

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.12 you can achieve this without the *hacky* `asyncio.sleep` calls via [`asyncio.eager_task_factory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#eager-task-factory)

> When using this factory, coroutines begin execution synchronously during Task construction. Tasks are only scheduled on the event loop if they block.

```py
import asyncio

async def subsubfunc():
    print("    subsubfunc")
    # [some async I/O code here]

async def subfunc():
    print("  subfunc A")
    awaitable = asyncio.create_task(subsubfunc())
    print("  subfunc B")
    await awaitable
    print("  subfunc C")

async def func():
    print("func A")
    awaitable = asyncio.create_task(subfunc())
    print("func B")
    await awaitable
    print("func C")

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
loop.set_task_factory(asyncio.eager_task_factory)
loop.run_until_complete(func())
```

---

By the way, using `asyncio.sleep(0)` is a valid way to allow other tasks to run and is documented in the [`asyncio` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep):

> sleep() always suspends the current task, allowing other tasks to run.
>
> Setting the delay to 0 provides an optimized path to allow other tasks to run. This can be used by long-running functions to avoid blocking the event loop for the full duration of the function call.